# Propagate ServiceSecurityContext

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, impersonation

I have a Winform application which calls a WCF service. The problem is that this service (A) calls itself another one (B) which wants to access the **ServiceSecurityContext.Name** of the initial caller (Winform's identity).

Both are hosted on IIS and use a NetTcpBinding.

I tried to add this attribute on service B method:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true,Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

And I added an Endpoint's behavior on service A:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="impBehavior">
    <clientCredentials>
        <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
    </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

But that doesn't work. What can I do?

Best regard,

Stéphane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. The problem was that I configured the client's endpoint behavior on the wrong place.

It should be configured at the Winform's level (which has service A as client) and not on the service itself (which has service B as client).

Everything works as expected now.

Thanks for your help.

Gtz,
Stéphane.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I think impersonation should be required and not simply allowed.

The simplest way to achieve that is to add a service behavior in your service B configuration file with this element:

```
<serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If Service B is on a different server then Service A, this won't work because impersonation can't "double hop" without very specific AD privileges given to the server (that admins typically won't give out because they have significant security implications).

If A and B are on the same server, then it should work if A's call to B is set to use impersonation (and the call to A allows it).